# Snapd login error

Tags: 20.04, snap

I install wsl2 ubuntu in windows 10 and I tried to install snapd to install anbox in it but when I try to login into snap its give me this error

```
╭─[~]─[mistrysiddh@MrFoxie]─[0]─[798]
╰─[:)] % snap  version                                                                                       [20:02:26]
snap    2.48.3+20.04
snapd   2.48.3+20.04
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
╭─[~]─[mistrysiddh@MrFoxie]─[0]─[799]
╰─[:)] % uname -a                                                                                            [20:02:37]
Linux MrFoxie 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
╭─[~]─[mistrysiddh@MrFoxie]─[0]─[800]
╰─[:)] % lsb_release -a                                                                                      [20:02:49]

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
╭─[~]─[mistrysiddh@MrFoxie]─[0]─[801]
╰─[:)] %                                                                                                     [20:03:04]
╭─[~]─[mistrysiddh@MrFoxie]─[0]─[801]
╰─[:)] % sudo snap login                                                                                     [20:03:07]
Personal information is handled as per our privacy notice at
https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/dataprivacy/snap-store

Email address: example@gmail.com
Password of "example@gmail.com":
error: access denied (see 'snap help login')
╭─[~]─[mistrysiddh@MrFoxie]─[1]─[802]
╰─[:(] %
```

Comment: is that your email address? if so I suggest you edit it out.

Comment: yes that's my email address and when I check online it's working fine

Comment: not a good idea to publish your email address on an open system - suggest you edit it out on your question.

Comment: thank you for suggestions